# Angular2 private variable not updated in ngOnChanges()

Tags: angular

I have a strange problem I am not able to solve for several hours.

In my component I have:

```
@Input() content : string;

private contentPreview : any;

ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges)  {
    this.contentPreview = changes['content'].currentValue;
    console.log(changes['content'].currentValue);   // <-- WORKS
}
```

The variable this.contentPreview  is not changed. If I try displaying it, it remains undefined. Even if I try this.contentPreview = "X";   it keeps undefined everywhere else in the component.

Am I missing something, or is it a bug?

Comment: This is probably caused by the fact that the change detection cycle has already finished. So a single change to 'content' triggers the onChanges hook, it update the contentPreview var, but that is the end of the change detection cycle so the DOM is not updated after that.

Comment: You can probably solve this using the doCheck hook, find more here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html#!#onchanges

Comment: Mike, thanks! I get the cycle point. However, I tried to display the private variable after another event (e.g. click on a component) and the value was not stored. Is it how it is supposed to work?

Comment: Mike, in ngDoCheck, I can see the variable containing the proper content. But how to refresh the componentn to display it?

Comment: Hmm.. can you post your template?

Comment: it is just a div

<div>{{contentPreview}}</div>

Comment: You would need something in your template that triggers an event in order for it to update this way.

Comment: I tried that. Click on div updates a number that is shown bellow. The number is incremented properly, but the contentPreview variable still unchanged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't actually reproduce your issue. But you could try and force the update with **[NgZone](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/NgZone-class.html)**, since you said the `console.log` is working, so that means that the hook is at least called, but for some reason it's not updating the DOM. So try:

In your child component:

```
import {NgZone} from '@angular/core'
```

inject it in constructor:

```
constructor(private ngZone: NgZone) { }
```

and then in your `OnChanges`:

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
   this.ngZone.run(() => this.contentPreview = changes['content'].currentValue;) 
}
```

**Here's a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/klyfJn5RsPyrFNz8YwND?p=preview)**

Comment: Thanks for your time! What I see in Chrome is, that the content is actually put into "ng-reflect-content-t"  within the <child> component. And the component still contains the initial value.  Any idea on this, please?

Comment: Hmm. Could you try and reproduce the issue in a plunker? You could fork the one I provided and I'd be happy to take a look at it :)

Comment: My script looks pretty much like yours, but the template is not rendered. Instead, the data is stored into ng-reflect-variablename

Comment: I created production files and it does work. I only see this issue on localhost:3000.  Any idea what might be wrong?